# two identical ByteBuffers behaving differently

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have two ByteBuffers, they are completely identical but somehow behave differently when used in the `GL11.glTexImage2D();` method.

My code:

```java
IntBuffer width = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
IntBuffer height = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
IntBuffer comp = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);

ByteBuffer data = STBImage.stbi_load("dsc8x12.bmp", width, height, comp, 4);

byte[] bytes = new byte[data.limit()];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = data.get(i);
}
ByteBuffer data2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);

System.out.println(data.equals(data2));

GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, 1024, 12, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

The console output is `true`

Here is how the window looks when the final argument in the `GL11.glTexImage2D();` is either `data` or `data2`

When `data` is used:
[image: when data is used]

When `data2` is used:
[image: when data2 is used]

Comment: When `data` is initialized with `STBImage.stbi_load(...)`, what `ByteOrder` is being used? Keep in mind that `ByteBuffer#wrap` creates a `ByteBuffer` with a `BIG_ENDIAN` `ByteOrder`, which may not be identical to the `ByteOrder` being used in `data`.

Comment: Why would byte order have anything to do with this.  Isn't a ByteBuffer a stream of individual bytes?  Wouldn't the byte order only come into this if you tried to, for example, read integers from the buffer?  I don't see how byte order could affect comparing two ByteBuffer objects.

Comment: Reading the definition of `ByteBuffer.equals()`, it says: "The two sequences of remaining elements, considered independently of their starting positions, are pointwise equal."  I wonder what that "remaining elements" means.  Could it be that the two buffers are very different despite their "remaining elements" being the same?  Like maybe they both have no "remaining elements".  I figure this idea is not that likely, but I figured it couldn't hurt to throw it out there.  I can't think what else it could be.

Comment: @Steve "Wouldn't the byte order only come into this if you tried to, for example, read integers from the buffer?" - Precisely, that's probably what's happening when `GL11.glTexImage2D` is invoked. "I don't see how byte order could affect comparing two ByteBuffer objects." - It doesn't, as `ByteBuffer#equals` does not compare the `ByteOrder` of both buffers before calling `ByteBuffer#mismatch`.

Comment: @JacobG. `STBImage.stbi_load(...)` gives ByteBuffer with `LITTLE_ENDIAN` ByteOrder, how do I clone ByteBuffers?

Comment: @Barbo24 Using `ByteBuffer#wrap` is fine, but you can try the following to change the `ByteOrder`: `ByteBuffer data2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);`

Comment: @JacobG. Tried it, no luck :(

Comment: @JacobG.- Duh.  I totally get it now.  I was being stupid.  The byte order would affect how the GL library interprets the data.  Of course. - So now that I get what you were saying, it sounds very promising as a cause and potential solution.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you get two different results with the two different ByteBuffers is that LWJGL *only* works with *direct* NIO Buffers, that is, ByteBuffers that are *not* backed by arrays.

The reason for this particular output that you are getting is two-fold:

1. the non-direct ByteBuffer you supply (the one being created by `.wrap(array)`) has an internal *address* field value of `0`. This is what LWJGL looks at when it actually calls the native OpenGL function. It reads that *address* field value and expects this to be the virtual memory address of the client memory to upload to the texture.
2. Now, there are some OpenGL functions that will just SEGFAULT when given an invalid pointer, such as zero. However, in this case, the `glTexImage2D` function is actually semantically overloaded, as when it receives the zero address as the last argument, it will only *allocate* texture memory of the requested size (here the `remaining` size of the ByteBuffer) and *not* move any client memory to the server (i.e. the GPU).

The ByteBuffer returned by `STBImage.stbi_load` *is* direct, and hence, the correct texture memory from the client's virtual memory address space is uploaded to OpenGL.

So, in essence: When you use LWJGL, you *must* always *only* use *direct* NIO Buffers, *not* ones that are wrappers of arrays!

Comment: So how am I supposed to copy the texture so that it creates a direct buffer that I can supply to OpenGL?

Comment: I only need a part of the bitmap im loading, so i thought copying only part of it would do the job but as it turns out it creates a non direct buffer, so how can i copy a part of it into a direct buffer?